# How to write css into a php snippet

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I need to add some css to a line of code, but not sure how to write it without breaking my site and getting a syntax error.

Id like to add a float to this piece of code:

```
<? wc_get_template( 'single-product/product-thumbnails.php'); ?>
```

I tried

`<? wc_get_template( 'single-product/product-thumbnails.php') {'style="float: left"'}; ?>`

This didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that this is possible? :-)

Comment: Can't you add a class and write css for that? as don't think it's possible without any html code.

Answer (score 2):

CSS is for HTML, not for PHP. Wrap this code in some `div` and apply style:

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <?php wc_get_template( 'single-product/product-thumbnails.php'); ?>
</div>
```

---

I don't know `Woocomerce`, but according to [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_template.html) documentation and [this](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/overriding-templates-in-woocommerce-extensions/) tutorial you can pass second parameter `$args`. So if these args are valid to accept `style`, then your code would look like this:

```
<?php
wc_get_template(
    'single-product/product-thumbnails.php',
    [
        'style' => 'float: left'
    ]
);
?>
```

Comment: as much as your suggestion did work for my purposes in this current example, i still have seen css written inline with php before, using items like echo and print to give the final result. Im not an expert though, hence why i was asking for expertise on how to write it like that.

Comment: Yes, you can echo anything, even styles. `echo '<div style="float: left">xxx</div>';` But the problem in your case is that `wc_get_template` is a function call that you can's change the semantics of.

Comment: @WillingLearner I don't know where you seen that, but your code would lead to syntax error. Maybe it was passed as string/object to some function?

Comment: not echo and print per se, but using concatenation to write out the snippet, then echo and print the final result. i don't know